# Parse.com object disappears after saving

Tags: ios, parse-platform

This is a bit of a crazy one. I have an IOS app that saves an object to Parse.com's datastore. Until a couple of days ago everything worked well. Now, suddenly, the object is not going into the database. I would put the code here but it doesn't seem to be the issue, as it gets even more bizarre:

When I go directly to the data browser and insert a row manually, it shows up right there.

But when I refresh the data browser -- the object is gone.

Looking at the forums here's some more data:

1. When I save from the app, I have an existing current user.
2. The object itself exists.
3. The permissions on my class are all "Public."
4. The app codes are correct (I'm able to read from the database.)
5. I'm even seeing the `saveInTheBackground` success block getting called, and printing out the object it has a valid object id!!!

But then it goes pooooooffff and is gone.

Any idea what's happening?

EDIT: I added a different class with the exact same columns, changed the appropriate fields in the app, and now everything works. But this is obviously alarming, that a class stops saving objects all of a sudden. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea unless you give us some ideas to verified the defect and suggest a solution.

Comment: @ldindu I go to the Data Browser on Parse.com. I click on the class name and then on the +Row button. I manually fill up some of the columns and hit enter. The row is saved. My afterSave method is getting triggered, and does its thing. Then I click the refresh button on the Data Browser -- and my newly inserted row is gone. The class has 54k rows. I tried deleting several hundred (it's in dev sp mp big deal) but it didn't help. When I insert values into other classes of this app it works fine. I don't know what else to say. Which additional info do you need?

Comment: I edited the question with new info. Basically changed to a different class / table and everything works. But... this is obviously alarming, that a Parse class suddenly stops accepting objects to save.

Comment: According to a person on the Parse team this is probably a valid bug. They're working on it.